# jQuery remove() for removing object by variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var rowResult = $(template(data)).find(".progressBar").progressbar({ value : 0 }).end();
this.jQueryDialog.find("ul#filesList").append(rowResult); 

$(rowResult).on("click", "button.removeButton", function()  { 
       $("ul#filesList").remove(rowResult);
 });
```

Why does append() work but remove() throws a type error?:

```
TypeError: expr.replace is not a function
Line: expr = expr.replace(rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" );     jquery.js
```

Comment: `$(rowResult, "ul#filesList").remove();`

Comment: This worked, thanks. For anyone using Typescript, I actually tried this but second guessed myself as the compiler wouldn't let it pass. I added a definition for it in JQueryStatic. (object: JQuery, context: any): JQuery;   Please post as answer if you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out

```
$(rowResult).on("click", "button.removeButton", function()  { 
       $(rowResult, "ul#filesList").remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes, your original answer didn't work, and the edit is just silly to re-run the entire template. adeneo has the answer, thanks

Comment: let me modify my answer according to Adeneo.. Thanks to Adeneo from my side also.. Please dont mark it as an answer...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think remove takes any arguments.

try  $("ul#filesList").remove();

Comment: I dont need to remove the whole list, just the row

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm:

```
$(rowResult).on("click", "button.removeButton", function()  { 
   $(this).remove();
});
```

I used to avoid using "this" in JS, but once you learn how to use it right, it can be very helpful.